# jQuery trigger click event not working on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a click event on a `div`. I use the following code but it is not working.

```
$('#showbanner').trigger('click');
```

```html
<div id="showbanner">show banner</div>
```

What is that I am doing wrong? I actually want to show the banner 2 seconds after page is loaded. Before I could add delay event my click event for this div is not firing.

Here is my code example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzyxo

Comment: What effect are you expecting the `click` to have? Do you have an event attached to that `div` element?

Comment: check simply your jquery is working or not..

Comment: try surrounding that div with a clickable element like `a` tag

Comment: As Luthando said, try to give a dimension to your div. Maybe you're clicking outside it without knowing.

Comment: Why -1? i am not here for upvote. plz explain why down vote is given so i can learn from you.

Comment: It looks like.. Your Script is executing first and then your html is executing. Put your script at the end or put it in a document.ready function. It will work.

Comment: @alok_dida it's already in a document.ready handler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because your `trigger('click');` call is the first thing in your script; it's called *before* the event is attached.

You need to move it to the end of the script so that the event handlers are bound when it is called:

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNyVvG)

Comment: @alok_dida I don't understand what you mean - the code is already in a document.ready handler...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I explained why in my answer - it's because you call `trigger()` ***before*** you attach the events. You need to call it *after*

Comment: Yes, got your point, sorry to ask how can i add delay to it `.delay(2000)`

Comment: No i meant like this `$('#hbanner').delay(2000).trigger('click');`

Comment: `delay()` only works for methods which use the queue, such as `animate()`. For others, you would need to use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

Try this .

```
$(function () {


    $(document).on("click", "#showbanner", function () {
        alert('Hola');
    });

    $("#showbanner").click();

});
```

show banner

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**JS**

```
$('#showbanner').on("click", function() { 
 alert("test");
});

$('#showbanner').trigger('click');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="showbanner">show banner</div>
```

Comment: I tried this also but still not working i have updated by question with example of complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
$('#showbanner').on("click", function() { 
 alert("test");
});

$('#showbanner').click();
```