# How to click a Div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that will simulate clicking around on a page.

However the links on the page look something:

[image]

I realize `.click()` is used for on `<button ..>` right? I'm guessing he has an event handler set up when something "clicks" that.

How can I simulate clicking that from jQuery?

Comment: `$('.quickAddItem-0-161').trigger('click')`.

Comment: You can haz XPath and use that instead? Click is not just for button. Click can be on anything. If you subscribe to click.. then you will get data with X,Y position on it and the element clicked. If the element has an actions, say a button, href, then it triggers the defaultAction of that element, or the function bound to it, or the onClick= attribute or any other magix found in the Eval() of that element click event

Comment: When and where in your code are you clicking the element? When and where are you binding the event listener? `.click()` should work iff you make sure [the DOM is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212), _then_ bind the listener, [_then_ simulate the click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29912369/4642212). Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) instead of a picture_) instead of a picture_).

Comment: @Xufox this is a chrome exntesion running on a page someone else has written. I'm just inspecting the console and trying to write a simple script that will click a link.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a `click` by triggering the click event. Something like this:

```
$(".quickAddItem-0-161").trigger("click");
```

Comment: That will click all elements with that class.. may be undesirable but yea.. #works

Answer (score 0):

there's many methods, you can check jquery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
examples :

```
$(divSelector).click();
//
$(divSelector).on('click',callback);
```

`divSelector` may be an `id` or `class` in your case `divSelector` is "quickAddItem-0-161"

Comment: The first one is correct. The second one sets up a click handler, which isn't what OP is trying to do.